# Existence of solution for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

This is a homework question but no hint is given. I think it is related to comparison principle of the ordinary differential equation.
Let f be a $C^{1}$ -function in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ such that $|f(x,y)|\leq 1+|y|$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbf{R}^{2}$ Show that the initial value problem
$$y'=f(x,y), x(0)=0$$ has a solution y(x) for all $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$

My try is
Let $E(x)=\frac{1}{2}|y(x)|^{2}$,then $|E'(x)|=|y(x)\dot y'(x)|\leq C |y|(1+|y|)\leq C_{0}(1+|E(x)|)$

Then $E(x)\leq (E(0)+1)exp(C_{0} x)-1$ and E(x) never blow up thus y is globally defined.
I am not sure whether this is the standard answer because comparison principle or Gronwall's inequality is not taught in my course but this is the only way I can figure it out.
Are there any other methods?  Any help is appreciated!